# My folder and application icons on Windows 7 are generic

Tags: windows-7, icons

All of a sudden my folder and application icons are sometimes generic icons, how do you fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open cmd.exe and type the following command

```
del %userprofile%\appdata\local\iconcache.db /a:h
```

now change your screen bit depth to 16 bit and then back to 32 bit.

restart explorer (log off and on again)