# Application icons are gone

Tags: windows-7, icons

Today I have installed an `exe icon changer` application unfortunately this application did not work as expected, so I decided to uninstall this...

I can't remember the application name, but I remember that while I was uninstalling this, there was an message on the uninstaller saying: `Restoring icons from windows-cache.` and uninstaller did freeze with 100% progress bar, after restarting my PC I can not see any application icons anymore.

Here is an screen-shot from my start menu, the same happends on my desktop.

[image]

/sorry for my English.

Comment: I had something like this happen many moons ago on Windows XP. Unfortunately, I never found a fix, other than manually changing the icons back which (sometimes) worked. Hope you have better luck than I did...

Comment: Thank you, I cant work with the icons looking like this `:S` I hope I do not have to re-install the Windows :/.

Comment: The *Kalkulator* entry shows an icon. What’s special about that one? `o.O` Do `.ico` files show correctly or are they blank as well? What about `.jpg`, `.png`, etc? What about `.bat`, `.zip`, `.txt` and other file types? Do folders look have a folder icon or are they blank too?

Comment: `Kalkulator` is a `Calculator`, Microsoft application - all Microsoft applications have correct icons. `*.ico`, `*.zip`, `*.rar`, `*.bat`, `*.txt` are also fine, it seems like there are only problems with exe files.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Whenever icons or thumbnails are not displaying correctly in Windows, there are several steps to try/check:

1. Rebuild the icon cache:

   - Automatically:

     1. Run the *Disk Cleanup* tool (`cleanmgr.exe`)
     2. Select `Thumbnails`, then `OK`
     3. Reboot?
   - Manually from Explorer:

     1. Open your local application data folder:

        - 2000/XP: `%userprofile%\Local Settings\Application Data`
        - Vista/7  : `%localappdata%`
     2. Delete the file `IconCache.db` (you will need to have hidden files visible)
     3. Reboot
   - Manually from the command-prompt:

     1. Open a command-prompt (`cmd.exe`)
     2. Change to local-app-data: `C:\> cd "<dir from step 1 above>"`
     3. Delete the icon cache:       `C:\…Local…> del /a IconCache.db`
     4. Reboot
2. Check for custom icon-handlers:

   1. Open a command-prompt (`cmd.exe`)
   2. Type `assoc EXT` where `EXT` is the extension of the problem file-type e.g.:

      `C:\> assoc .exe`

      `.exe=exefile`
   3. Navigate to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\<file-type>\ShellEx`, where `file-type` is the result you got from the previous command (e.g., `exefile`)
   4. See if there is an `IconHandler` subkey/branch under `ShellEx`

      (Some file-types such as shortcuts (`.lnk` files) *need* an icon-handler)
   5. If so, delete it or just rename it (e.g., to `#IconHandler`, `IconHandler-`, etc.)
   6. Refresh the desktop/window with the files
3. Check for “Old Icon”s:

   1. Find the extension association as in steps 2.2-2.3
   2. Navigate to the CLSID in the `IconHandler` (e.g. `HKCR\CLSID\{42042206-2D85-11D3-8CFF-005004838597}`)
   3. Check if there is an `Old Icon` subkey, if so, expand it
   4. Examine the subkeys under `Old Icon` and make sure that the `DefaultIcon`s are correct (they **cannot** contain quotes and **must** contain an icon index—even if just `,0`—for non-icon files such as `.dll`, `.exe`, or `.icl`)
4. Set the icon to “self” for files containing their icon (e.g., `.exe`, `.ico`, `.bmp`…):

   - Using the registry editor:

     1. Determine the file-type as in steps 2.1 - 2.2 above
     2. Run the registry editor (`regedit.exe`)
     3. Navigate to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\<file-type>\DefaultIcon`
     4. Set the default value to `"%1"`
     5. Refresh
   - Using a file:

     1. Create a plain-text file with a text-editor (e.g., `notepad.exe`)
     2. Type or copy-paste the following (remember to replace the file-type):

        `REGEDIT4`                               

        `[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\<file-type>\DefaultIcon]`

        `@="\"%1\""`
     3. Save the file as `Reset_Icon.reg` (**not** `Reset_Icon.reg.txt`)
     4. Double-click the `.reg` file to merge it into the registry
     5. Refresh
5. Ensure that thumbnails are enabled (Vista and up):

   1. Open the *Folder Options* dialog:

      - Open `shell:::{6DFD7C5C-2451-11d3-A299-00C04F8EF6AF}`

        or
      - From an Explorer window, the menu `Tools->Folder Options…`
   2. Select the *View* tab
   3. Un-check the *Always show icons, never thumbnails* option
   4. Refresh

Comment: No results :/ still I still see the 'blank' icons.

Comment: For *everything*? From your screenshot, it looks like *some* things are showing correctly.

Comment: Not for everything, I can see the Microsoft related icons, like: `My Computer`, `Recycle Bin`, `Documents`, `MSN` and I can also see all folders icons. The problem appears when there are some external applications icons to appear.

Comment: Okay good. That means that only the `.exe` files are incorrect (the other items you mentioned are not program files; they are special and have their own icons). So use the registry script I added to my answer to reset the icon for `.exe` files.

Comment: Well, I can't believe it, but it still does not work. :/ I've saved your registry entry into a `Reset_EXE_Icons.reg` file and then I run it and accepted the warning, then message box appear saying that the entry has been successfully added... I did reboot, but still no results...

Comment: Open `Regedit.exe` and navigate to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\DefaultIcon`. What is the default value in the [pane to the right](http://i.imgur.com/9BeGF.png)?

Comment: I got the same value as on the screenshot you gave.

Comment: Maybe the program set it to show icons instead of thumbnails. Try resetting it as above.

Comment: It was unchecked by default.

Comment: It may not be executables at all, it could shortcuts. Open a folder that has `.exe` files in it. Do they have the correct icons? Create a shortcut to one of them (hold `Alt` then drag and drop an `.exe` file). Does the shortcut have the correct icon?

Comment: shortcut doesnt have icons, same as executable files at all.

Comment: *> shortcut doesnt have icons, same as executable files at all.* Shortcuts do not have icons. Executables do or do not? Check `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\lnkfile\shellex\IconHandler` to see if the default value is `@="{00021401-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"` If so, then that program seems to have broken something in an unusual way, which will require some more work to figure out…

Comment: Executables do not have icons. `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\lnkfile\shellex\IconHandler` is `{00021401-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}`

Comment: I've fixed this by removing the registry data on `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\` . Thank you :-).

Comment: Huh? It sounds like that program installed some kind of custom handler (in the `shellex` subkey). That could be removed without deleting the whole `exefile` branch. You completely removed the `exefile` branch? Do executable files still work?

Comment: Yes, everything is working, and you're right, there was some custom handlers.

Comment: Okay, great. If you remember what the program was, add it to the question so that future users of it can have an idea about fixing it (and perhaps someone filing a complaint with them about their uninstaller).

Comment: Sure, I will :-).

Comment: I was trying to figure out why in Windows 7 I have a Chromium icon for `.html` files, but in Windows XP, I get a blank icon. While investigating, I figured out that there is indeed another mechanism that relates to the displaying of icons and thumbnails that some programs mess with [just as I thought](http://superuser.com/questions/71652/windows-7-image-thumbnails-fail-to-appear#comment447271_71652). I’ve added it to the answer. I suspect that the program you used had installed an IconHandler which of course is now gone.

Comment: Yeah I've never had this happen to me before, but it just did, and none of the listed steps have worked either.  This suspiciously occurred right after I just ran CCleaner

Comment: @Synetech My `DefaultIcon` values for `.jpg` and `.png` files is set to `%SystemRoot%\System32\imageres.dll,-83` Is that odd?

Comment: #1, third bulleted item works, but with one alteration as described here. http://superuser.com/a/613868/387576

Comment: This solved it for me! http://superuser.com/questions/71652/windows-7-image-thumbnails-fail-to-appear/613868#613868

Answer (score 3):

Since all normal procedures to fix icons problems (and detailled here by Synetech) wont works, I supposed the problem comes from remaining elements of the failed uninstallation of this unknown application...

*Suggestion #1:* Try this [My folder and application icons on Windows 7 are generic](https://superuser.com/questions/17409/my-folder-and-application-icons-on-windows-7-are-generic) *N.B.:* same of the Synetech solution #1 except with this difference:
«change your screen bit depth to 16 bit and then back to 32 bit»

*Suggestion #2:* Try this Ms Fix it: [«*Fix problems with programs that can't be installed or uninstalled*»](http://support.microsoft.com/mats/Program_Install_and_Uninstall)

*Suggestion #3:* Try a system restore…

Hope this help.

Comment: For you it's a minor problem not for the user. System restore is a normal fixing procedure (like restoring a backup... for example) not a reformat which is useless in 99,99% of the case (good for n00bZ imnsho...). Have a nice day Synetech!  Keep smile :)))

Comment: Suggestion #1 worked for me.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've tried a few different things. The thing that worked for me was [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/49819-icon-cache-rebuild.html).

This page has two options:

1. An automatic option: Download a batch file and run it
2. A manual option (I assume this contains the contents of the automatic option batch file):

   - ie4uinit.exe -ClearIconCache
   - taskkill /IM explorer.exe /F
   - DEL "%localappdata%\IconCache.db" /A
   - shutdown /r /f /t 00

I've had the trouble twice. Today, the first command from the manual option fixed the problem.

Good luck!