# Application icons and associated shortcuts are generic

Tags: windows-10, icons

All of a sudden this morning my application icons are "generic." System application icons such as Explorer, Task Manager, etc are not affected. Other file types such as txt, pdf, jpg, etc are not affected either. Shortcuts to the affected applications are generic too.

The icons are generic in the taskbar and in Windows Explorer. They are not generic in the Start menu.

This question [Application icons are gone](https://superuser.com/questions/393735/application-icons-are-gone) seems the most similar to my own, and I have tried I think all of the solutions offered in the accepted answer. However, these solutions don't seem to work.

I rebuilt the icon cache. I checked the exefile key in regedit and didn't see anything unusual. I checked the view option in Windows Explorer. I've rebooted at least twice. I'm on Windows 10.